# Overflow error when performing operation on large integers

Tags: python

I was trying out a problem from HackerRank when I came across a problem in python dealing with a large integer

My Code :

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def repeatedString(s, n):
    a_count = 0
    for item in list((s*(int(n/len(s))+1))[0:n]):
        if item=='a':
            a_count += 1
    return a_count

if __name__ == '__main__':

    s = input()

    n = int(input().strip())

    result = repeatedString(s, n)

    print(str(result) + '\n')
```

Input :

```
a
1000000000000
```

Error :

```
for item in list((s*(int(n/len(s))+1))[0:n]):
OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

The code works with smaller integers but throws this error when working with large integers any ideas or suggestions on how to get around this problem?

Comment: What is `sys.maxsize` - if you have a 32 bit python, max list size may be less than you want.

Comment: As an aside, I think `for item in s*(int(n/len(s))+1):` is sufficient. Slicing the whole string and then making a whole new list of it will really explode memory usage.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, I have a 32-bit python but it also gives Memory Error while using the HackerRank compiler. I also tried the change you suggested but it did not make a difference.

Comment: In cpython, integers can be of any size, but other things like containers (lists, strings, etc) are limited to C data sizes. A list is a C list of pointers to python objects, so are limited to 32 bit integers (on your 32 bit python).

Comment: You entered a huge number and the values generated just don't fit in memory. You may want to write some sort of a generator. For the example "a" its easy, just emit "a" however many times you want. For a larger string, you just need to keep repeating through the string instead of prebuilding the entire source string.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do? What result do you want to achieve?
For a moment forget about the whole code just focus on

```
list((s*(int(n/len(s))+1))[0:n]):
```

if you print this you know its not only about integer.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

s = input()

n = int(input().strip())
lst=list((s*(int(n/len(s))+1))[0:n])
print('list',lst)
```

it can print **s**, **n** number of times. so it can the memory

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dxNh.png]

Comment: Thank You for the answer, I understood the problem came when creating a list of size "1000000000000" so I took a different approach to the problem like @tdelaney suggested.